# I am unable to render a flatlist in react native and solutions aren't working

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I tried rendering a flatlist in react native with data from a json file but it is not working.

JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "1",
    "user_name": "user1",
    "user_display_name": "User 1"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "2",
    "user_name": "user2",
    "user_display_name": "User 2"
  },
]
```

This is my index.js file code. A contact list with search functionality:
I implemented the search functionality using useEffect hook to check when the search bar changes and filter the JSON file I am importing (dummyContacts)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, TextInput, Pressable } from "react-native";
import dummyContacts from "../../../assets/data/contacts.js";

export default function ContactsScreen() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [filteredContacts, setFilteredContacts] = useState(dummyContacts);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newContacts = dummyContacts.filter(contact =>
      contact.user_display_name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredContacts(newContacts);
  },[searchTerm]);


  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <TextInput
        value={searchTerm}
        onChangeText={setSearchTerm}
        style={styles.searchInput}
        placeholder="Search  ksboeli swin Contact name"
      />

      <FlatList
        data={filteredContacts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text style={styles.contactPage} > {item.user_display_name}</Text>)}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.seperatorLine} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    flex:1,
  },
  contactPage: {
    fontSize: 17,
    marginVertical: 12,
  },
  seperatorLine: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
  searchInput: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
});
```

This is my app.js file:
Not sure what to do. Im stuck

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import ContactsScreen from './src/screens/ContactScreen';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} />

      <ContactsScreen />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
    data={filteredContacts}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text style={styles.contactPage} > {item.user_display_name}</Text>)}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.seperatorLine} />}
    kexExtractor={item => item.user_id}
/>
```

Comment: Did you try running this solution? Contacts were not rendered :(